# Define a constant that can be used in module/controller/etc. definition in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, constants

I would like to put module name, controller name etc. to string constants, so that I can easily change them if the need be (compared to fixing it in each and every file).

So I have this code:

```
 angular
    .module("app.admin.home")
    .controller("HomeController", HomeController);
```

And I would like it have this (or similar):

```
 angular
    .module(moduleConstants.admin)
    .controller(controllerConstants.adminHome, HomeController);
```

Is there a proper way to define this type of constants in Angular (ordinary injection does not work in this case). I guess I can create just global javascript constants, but maybe there is a better way of achieving this, some common way to define constants in angular. I have a strong C# background and it sounds stupid to me that constants need to be injected, they are not abstract code that can have different implementation, so it sounds wrong to inject it rather than just reference.

Comment: you can you $rootScope too

Answer (score 1):

To avoid polluting the global name space, you could use a closure:

```
(function (moduleConstants, controllerConstants) {
    angular
        .module(moduleConstants.admin)
        .controller(controllerConstants.adminHome, HomeController);
})({admin: "app.admin.home"},
   {adminHome: "HomeController"});
```

Comment: I would rather define the constants in a separate file, I am not sure how would be angular able to inject it in this case?

Comment: Welcome to the world of JavaScript. You are no longer in C# land.

Comment: Do you say it's impossible to do then this way? :)

Answer (score 0):

According with the documentation, the right way of defining constants using angular js is using: [Constants](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant)

This can be a simple implementation:

```
angular.module('config', [])
    .constant('CONSTANT_YOU_NEED', {
        name: 'test',
        valueOfConst: '3.14'
    });
```

But i guess you can't use this for modules or Controllers, but just passing to them

Comment: you can define them and pass it into your controllers,directives,etc